# Best way to implement 20 @RestController's in spring-framework without repeating yourself (DRY)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

After implementing about 20 rest controllers & services, I found myself that A LOT of my code was repeated, so I came up with this contraption.

CrudController.java
    package app.controllers;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import app.models.Model;
import app.services.CrudService;

@RestController
public abstract class CrudController<M extends Model, S extends CrudService<M, ? extends CrudRepository<M,Long>>> {
    S service;

    public abstract void setService(S service);
    public abstract Boolean isAuthorized(Long entityId, S service);

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public M create(M object) {
        if(isAuthorized(object.getId(), service)) {
            return service.save(object);
        }
        logUnauthorizedAccess();
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public M update(M object) {
        if(isAuthorized(object.getId(), service)) {
            return service.update(object);
        }
        logUnauthorizedAccess();
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Boolean delete(Long id) {
        if(isAuthorized(id, service)) {
            return service.delete(id);
        }
        logUnauthorizedAccess();
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody M get(Long id) {
        if(isAuthorized(id, service)) {
            return service.get(id);
        }
        logUnauthorizedAccess();
        return null;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<M> json(ModelMap map) {
        return service.getAll();
    }

    private void logUnauthorizedAccess() {
        System.out.println("!!UN-AUTHORIZED ACCESS DETECTED!!");
    }
}
```

CrudService.java

```
package app.services;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public abstract class CrudService<M extends app.models.Model, R extends CrudRepository<M, Long>> {
    R repo;

    public abstract void setRepo(R repo);

    /**
     * Define the parameters that you want to save to the DB when calling the update() method
     * @param from source object
     * @param to DB object that gets saves, "return to" in this method
     * @return
     */
    public abstract M copy(M from, M to);

    public Iterable<M> getAll() {
        return this.repo.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * Mainly used to create a new entity
     * however, can also be used to save something without using the
     * update() method.
     * @param model
     * @return saved entity model
     */
    public M save(M model) {
        return this.repo.save(model);
    }

    public M get(Long id) {
        return this.repo.findOne(id);
    }

    public M update(M model) {
        M updated = this.repo.findOne(model.getId());
        updated = copy(model, updated);
        return this.repo.save(updated);
    }

    public Boolean delete(Long id) {
        this.repo.delete(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
package app.models;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Model {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Date dateCreated;

    @Version
    private Timestamp dateModified;

    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.setDateCreated(new Date());
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(Timestamp dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }
}
```

Now all my controllers look like the following while giving me.
/create /get /update /delete /json

```
package app.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import app.models.Sample;
import app.services.SampleService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class SampleController extends CrudController<Sample, SampleService> {

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setService(SampleService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isAuthorized(Long entityId, SampleService service) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ddalcu/spring-starter/commit/27fb2a0719c4780d7cf648852d93b8fd3d8759c8

What do you guys think , good bad , better way to do it ?

Comment: your endpoints are not very restful this way; you have the verb in the url, while you could just use the http verb.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/).

Answer (score 1):

Spring is able to handle generics:

You dont really need to subclass the `CrudController` for each `Model` As long as the implementation inside does not change.

You can work with one controller that uses a `PathVariable` for the class for example.

Then you have the same possibility with the `CrudService` and `Dao` too.

If you see now that for some entities you need special treatment within this controller (or service, dao) you have at least two ways that I know of:

- create a complete new route for this entity type with controller, service and dao.
- do not simply use the crudservice inside the crudcontroller but autowire a list (or map) and lookup the correct service to continue the route.

This forking in the second or third layer depends mostly on where you need to have special possibilities.

I have seen both approaches and currently i use a mix of this myself in spring projects.
As the dispatcher servlet is ordering requestmappings according to how many variables you have it is easy to create a more concrete mapping by simply hardcode the part with the pathvariable for a specialised controller.